# power function and arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector, pow

I'm trying to write a function that will take an array or vector and have its values taken to a "power of" and then display it's values. I'm not too familiar with arrays but simply put I'm trying to create something like

```
n = {2^1, 3^1, 5^1,2^2,3^2,5^2,....}
```

the "power of" is going to be looped.
I then plan to sort the array, and display 1500th term.

this problem corresponds to prime number sequence only divisible by 2 , 3 & 5;
I'm trying to find a more time efficient way than just if statements and mod operators.

Comment: Can you please show some code of yours?

Comment: Generalized version of problem and solution here: http://usacotraining.blogspot.ca/2012/06/problem-313-humble-numbers.html

Comment: If you sort the array before calling the power_of() function, it will be faster, the function will most likely run faster and the result will already be sorted.

Comment: The Ugly Numbers problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly this is the Ugly Numbers problem I've faced some years ago in the UVa.

The idea to solve this problem is to use a priority queue with the numbers 2, 3 and 5 as initial values. At each step remove the topmost value **t** and insert the values **2*t**, **3*t** and **5*t** in the priority queue, repeat this steps till the 1500th term is found.

See this forum for more info: http://online-judge.uva.es/board/viewtopic.php?t=93